# Adjust height of React Cards without including collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

Im creating a web interface which is listing various processes and services. These are all listed in React cards which all support expand/collapse - expanding the cards and showing more information. The information shown in expand will vary in size and information and I don't want the cards to adjust height if a card is expanded. The height is aligned when they are collapsed, but I'm unsure to how to not adjust them when a card is expanded. Example:

[image: Uncollapsed Cards behaving as desired]
This image shows how the card height has been aligned to the card with the most content. This is the exact behaviour I want.

[image: Collapsed cards expanding wrongly]

The problem occurs when I expand one of the boxes. The content in the other boxes gets aligned to the new size. I want the expand function to not effect the heigh of the other cards.

The custom class of the cards is listed here:

```
const infoCard = makeStyles({
root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    height: "-webkit-fill-available"
}
})

const createCards:
   const classes = infoCard();
...
...
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardContent> "Add content" </CardContent>
        <Collapse>
          <CardContent> "Add content" </CardContent>
        </Collapse>
      </Card>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

I also want the result to support having additional rows of card below this row.

Does anyone know how to go around this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you meant _expand_ where you wrote _collapse_ and vice versa ;)

Comment: I believe the answer here will depend much on if you plan to have cards _below_ the existing ones? Are there ever going to be more than 1 card vertically placed, or will they all be horizontally aligned?

Comment: @Chris, You are correct. I edited the question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Chris: I plan on having multiple rows beneath as well. I simply want those to be pushed further down, all aligned in a similar manner as this (the top) row.

Comment: You could align them vertically so that each "column" is independent on its horizontally neighboring cards, but that might be a problem if you want an responsive design where cards can flow freely across a rows and columns. If that's the case I suggest looking into Mosaic layout libraries.

Comment: @Chris I do use an interactive responsive design, so they will adjust if screen size changes etc. I'll look into Mosaic and see if I find something there, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add
`align-items: flex-start;` 
to the styles of your root element, its stretch by default, which would stretch all the elements to be at the same height

```
const infoCard = makeStyles({
root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    height: "-webkit-fill-available"
}
})
```

Comment: The same error occurs with this, I'm afraid :(